# How can I separate the elements of one recyclerView from another when the number of elements causes scroll to be generated on the recycler?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

Every time I am adding elements within a recyclerView, at the moment of generating scroll I need that no more elements are added inside that viewHolder and later it is added to another one. Thank you very much

Comment: please add sample code

Comment: Are you asking how to make it so that a single `ViewHolder` is never re-bound to a different item in your recycler view?

Comment: No, what I want is that it generates a displacement inside a ViewHolder, another one is created from the elements that are needed so that I do not have to scroll